# Order by ASC in When case

Tags: mysql, case, case-when

here table named : table

```
|field1 | field 2
------------------
|def-toto    | agh

|abc-toto    | bij

|def         | agh-toto

|abc         | bij-toto
```

---

On the search 'toto', I want the result :

1. abc-toto bij
2. def-toto agh
3. def agh-toto
4. abc bij-toto

traduction => order by field 1 ASC (when field 1 like %toto%) then ORDER BY field 1 ASC (when field 2 like %toto%)

**So the request : not working:**

```
SELECT * FROM table

WHERE field1 LIKE '%toto%' OR field2 LIKE '%toto%'

ORDER BY

CASE
    WHEN nom_com LIKE '%$termeOk%'  THEN 1 ASC
    WHEN desc_com LIKE '%$termeOk%' THEN 2 ASC
END
```

Answer (score 0):

We can approach this by using a two-tiered sorting logic.  First, the records with `toto` appearing in `field1` will be sorted before those without this.  Then, within each of those two groups, another sort will happen.  The positive `toto` records get sorted by `field1`, and the negative `toto` records get sorted by `field2`.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE field1 LIKE '%toto%' OR field2 LIKE '%toto%'
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN field1 LIKE '%toto%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
    CASE WHEN field1 LIKE '%toto%' THEN field1 ELSE field2 END;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

try this

SELECT * FROM table

WHERE CONCAT(field1,field2 ) LIKE '%toto%'

ORDER BY field1,field2